# Axios interceptor setTimeout() working in dev but not after compile and deploy

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I have a delay built into my `axios` module for testing `react` UI spinners etc.

The mock_delay works perfectly on my local machine **but** after I `npm build` and deploy it appears the promise does not return.

If I set mock_delay false this works on both my local and remote (built, nginx) machine. But if I set a time out then, on the built server I see the "console.log('config.mock_delay' etc" but not the "console.log('response', response)".

Any clues??

```js
const Server = axios.create({
    baseURL: AUTH_API2_URL,
    timeout: 5000,
    mock_delay: false, //800,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': currentJWTHeader(),
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'accept': 'application/json'
    }
  })

Server.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  if (config.mock_delay) {
    console.log('config.mock_delay', config.mock_delay)
    return new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(() => resolve(config), config.mock_delay))
  }
  return config
})

Server.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    console.log('response', response)
    return response
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your local version work but for production it has reason for not working.

1st, the axios interceptor `use` requires function with signature like this: `req => req`. It means receive a request and return an enhanced request.
Ref here:

https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors

https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/interceptors

So with your code, it is correct when `mock_delay` is `false`: `config => config`

But when `mock_delay` is not `false`, it is `config => Promise`, then your code is failed because of wrong expectation => that's why you never see the `response`.

Let twist it a bit:

```
function delay(ms) {
    // my prev answer has a mistake
    // that is the `resolve` function is undefined
    // return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    // fix here
    return new Promise(() => setTimeout(() => {}, ms));
}

// remember to add async keywork
Server.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
  if (config.mock_delay) {
    console.log('config.mock_delay', config.mock_delay)
    // with await, this will wait for the time of mock_delay
    await delay(config.mock_delay)
  }

  // finally still return config
  return config
})
```

Comment: Thanks for trying @Khoa ! I gave this a but sadly exactly same thing. I even tried reducing the delay down to 20ms but it still only got as far as printing the console message :-(

Comment: @ErichBSchulz, I think I made a mistake - the `resolve` function is not defined. Let try this:
```javascript
function delay(ms) {
    return new Promise(() => setTimeout(()=>{}, ms));
}
```

Comment: sorry Khoa - I tried that and no change. Again works locally but on build and deploy as soon I set mock_delay it dies. I think it must be something to do with the build process??

Comment: actually no your updated delay function didn't work at all on either server or local machine (sorry)

Comment: my apologies too. nothing did help :cry: